# How to display a screen and making it stay in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a visual novel as my project. I decided to not use renPy as it would shorten the codes too much. Currently, I am trying to display the next line of text when a user clicks the next button. However, the button doesn't work. There are no errors but the python won't detect my clicks.

```
def main_game():
    running = True
    while running:
         screen.fill(black)
         s = pygame.Surface((1280, 200))
         s.set_alpha(50)                
         s.fill((white))

         screen.blit(s, (0,520))
         draw_text("", font2, purple, screen, 2, 522)
         draw_text("Before beginning your journey, please give yourself a name.", font3, white, screen, 15, 580)

         mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

         button_next = pygame.Rect(1117, 650, 150, 50)

         if button_next.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                next_story()

         pygame.draw.rect(screen, (white), button_next)

         font = pygame.font.Font("PixelDigivolve-mOm9.ttf", 30)
         text_next = font.render("NEXT", 1, (black))
         screen.blit(text_next, (1157, 655))

         click = False
         for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button == 1:
                        click = True

         pygame.display.update()
         mainClock.tick(60)
```

and here's the code for the next screen

```
def next_story():
    screen.fill(black)
    s = pygame.Surface((1280, 200))
    s.set_alpha(50)                
    s.fill((white))           
    screen.blit(s, (0,520))
    draw_text("", font2, purple, screen, 2, 522)
    draw_text("What shall you name yourself?", font3, white, screen, 15, 580)
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Does `click` becomes `True` on mouse click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From provided code: `click` becomes `True` on mouse click but you have `click = False` which is executed each time, so it immediately becomes `False` in next cycle. Remove this line of code and test it. And if you need to reset this flag put it inside another `if` with new logic.
Also remove from `next_story()`:

```
pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

you only need it once, in the main loop. Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: yep it helped! Thank you very much :)